# envfile syntax. How integers (like PORTs) should be written

Tags: python, django, environment-variables

I wonder if these configs are the same:

Config 1:

```
EMAIL_PORT=587
EMAIL_USE_TLS=True
EMAIL_USE_SSL=None
```

Config 2:

```
EMAIL_PORT='587'
EMAIL_USE_TLS='True'
EMAIL_USE_SSL='None'
```

settings.py (or just a random python file):

```
EMAIL_PORT = os.getenv('EMAIL_PORT')
EMAIL_USE_TLS = os.getenv('EMAIL_USE_TLS')
EMAIL_USE_SSL = os.getenv('EMAIL_USE_SSL')
```

Will my, let's say **EMAIL_PORT** in settings.py get a value of 587 or it will be '587' instead, or if **EMAIL_USE_TLS** will get the pythonic boolean `True` or `'True'` instead? What is the suggestion on assigning variables in envfile? How to handler such booleans, integers or any other non-string values?

thanks!

Comment: @SitiSchu, so it's not purposeful to set integers in envfiles? or I should get those values like this ```int(os.getenv('bla bla bla'))```?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the [Python Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.getenv) `os.getenv` will always return a `str`:

> key, default and the **result** are str.

(emphasis mine)

For the port you can simply do this:

```
EMAIL_PORT  = int(os.getenv('EMAIL_PORT'))
```

But for the Boolean I would set a value of 0 or 1 in the env so you can do the following:

Config:

```
EMAIL_USE_TLS=1
```

Python:

```
EMAIL_USE_TLS = bool(int(os.getenv('EMAIL_USE_TLS')))
```

Both these methods rely on the correctness of the environment variables so you might want to add error handling.

Comment: so it's not purposeful to set integers in envfiles? or I should get those values like this ```int(os.getenv('bla bla bla'))```?

Comment: @Docker You can set the envfile however you want, it will always be a string so its simply personal preference. I've updated my answer to get the values that you want